# Angular Factory getdata

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api

i´m trying to create a factory with angular.js and y have this json structure from the github api:

```
[
  {
    "login": "mojombo",
    "id": 1,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/mojombo",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  }]
```

i want to get the data from the url property that contain the info of the user and the idea is get that data from all the user.

this the my code so far from the factory:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('userFactory', function($http){

    function getData(){
      return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users');
    }
    function userData(){
      getData().success(function(data){
        return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users'+ data.url)
      }).error()
    }
    return{
      getData : getData
    }
  });
```

and this is the controller:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('listUserController', function($scope, userFactory){
    $scope.users;

    userFactory.getData().success(function(data){
      $scope.users = data;
    }).error(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    })


  });
```

but i can get the data, coul you help please.......

Answer (score 0):

Angular encapsulate the api response in an object, try

```
userFactory.getData().success(function(response){ // response instead of data
  $scope.users = response.data; // response.data instead of data
}).error(function(error){
  console.log(error);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the working plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tdA2qQ3FYksTm9wp8qpH?p=preview).

It does:

```
$resource(user.url)
```

To request for individual user for its data

```
result.push(userData)
```

Push to result and return to controller

```
userFactory.userData().then(function(data){
    vm.userData = data;
});
```

We're using $resource here because we want to keep the reference to the data in the result array. Then after response come from server, our result array will reflect the changes and show in the view.

Comment: i´m trying to make a ng-repeat with user followers but does not work help me......

Comment: because what i´m trying to do is get the data from the addres inside the URL property of all user, and then make a ng-repeat with that data to generate a list of users

Comment: can you check the plnkr again, a fixed it.

Comment: maybe a did not explain me self well, an example.....i want get all repository from all the user in URL that has the repos_url porperty to display it on view

Comment: Sorry, do you mean.

1. Get list of users.
2. Display list of User's repo urls
Ex: 
    - https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/repos
    - https://api.github.com/users/brynary/repos